# Trying to add swipe Gesture to simple app

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn android(studio) in the hopes of creating my own apps that others will enjoy in the near future. I'm trying to write a simple gesture app where when the user swipes left or right the textView widget will change.

Thanks in advance.

This isn't working code but I think I'm in the general space of what I want to do hopefully someone can make it a little clearer
What I have currently:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.chris.gestureproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleOnGestureListener {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button tapButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tapButton);

        tapButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
                        messageText.setText("I Got Tap");
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    SimpleOnGestureListener simpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                               float velocityY) {

            float sensitvity = 50;
            if ((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity) {
                SwipeLeft();
            } else if ((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity) {
                SwipeRight();
            }

            return true;
        }

    };

    GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
            simpleOnGestureListener);

    private void SwipeLeft() {

        TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        messageText.setText("Left Side Swiped");

    }


    private void SwipeRight() {

        TextView messageText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        messageText.setText("Right Side Swiped");
    }



}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830832/create-simple-gesture-for-swipe-left-to-right-and-right-to-left

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: I've edit the code to reflect what I'm trying to do. It doesn't work but hopefully it give a better idea to people who can help.