# Showing text gallery on application first time start up in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog

I am posting this question because I never worked on this and I am not aware which component is used to implement such functionality.

See this screen-shot. This is an sample image. It is not my work, this is taken from Google Images:

[image]

Now on application startup I am reading Android sd card and updating my database. In the meantime, I am using ProgressDialog like this

[image]

Now what I want is to show 5 image slides. Not Image slide I want a single colour backgroung and the text should have to be change every two seconds on the same backgroung with five small circles I downside.

Now I am not able to get what is it. A image slide show or other native component. I asked in chat rooms they asked me to post here.

If it can happen without image it will be better because there is a lot of complexities with different device sizes.

How can I implement this?

Comment: use viewFliper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461879/looking-for-android-viewflipper-example-with-multiple-webviews and http://android-journey.blogspot.in/2010/01/android-webview.html in thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [android smartimageview](https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view)  or with [Viewflow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow)

Comment: for am one time activity using such complex widgets according to me are not preferable. Do you have any smart way in sense of less memory consumption.

Comment: Can you explain in detail over here only.